# Different compile options for tests and release in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I have a project where I need to disable assertions when creating the binaries. Now I could just do:

```
scalacOptions += "-Xdisable-assertions"
```

But then also the unit tests would be run without assertions. Is there a (hopefully) simple way to achieve what I need?

Comment: `scalacOptions in Compile += "-Xdisable-assertions"`

Comment: @giladhoch This disables assertions everywhere.

Comment: maybe you can also add: `scalacOptions in Test ~= (_.filterNot(_ == "-Xdisable-assertions"))` , haven't tested it, but I think this should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you create the binaries? What task/command do you use?

Use the task as the scope for `scalacOptions` to have different values for them. See [Scoping by configuration axis](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html#scoping-by-configuration-axis):

> By default, all the keys associated with compiling, packaging, and
>   running are scoped to a configuration and therefore may work
>   differently in each configuration. The most obvious examples are the
>   task keys compile, package, and run; but all the keys which affect
>   those keys (such as sourceDirectories or scalacOptions or
>   fullClasspath) are also scoped to the configuration.

Use `inspect` when in doubt.

```
> inspect scalacOptions
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options for the Scala compiler.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/task-dependsOn/}task-dependson/compile:scalacOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1424
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  task-dependson/compile:autoCompilerPlugins
[info]  task-dependson/compile:settingsData
[info]  task-dependson/compile:update
[info]  task-dependson/compile:buildDependencies
[info]  task-dependson/compile:thisProjectRef
[info] Delegates:
[info]  task-dependson/compile:scalacOptions
[info]  task-dependson/*:scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/compile:scalacOptions
[info]  {.}/*:scalacOptions
[info]  */compile:scalacOptions
[info]  */*:scalacOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  b/compile:scalacOptions
[info]  b/test:scalacOptions
[info]  task-dependson/test:scalacOptions
[info]  task-dependson/jacoco:scalacOptions
[info]  a/jacoco:scalacOptions
[info]  */*:scalacOptions
[info]  a/test:scalacOptions
[info]  a/compile:scalacOptions
[info]  b/jacoco:scalacOptions
```

The `Compile` configuration scope is the default one (see `show defaultConfiguration` for a project) so `scalacOptions += "-Xdisable-assertions"` is in fact `scalacOptions in Compile += "-Xdisable-assertions"`. Use different configuration, say `Test`, and you'll get different results.

There's however a hitch in SBT (I missed the very first time I responded) - settings are chained and when a setting is not defined in a scope, it gets its value from a more general scope. When I said, *`scalacOptions +=...` is in fact `scalacOptions in Compile`* I missed the important feature of settings - `scalacOptions` is global while `scalacOptions in Compile` is `Compile`-scoped.

Comment: What I ultimately want to have without assertions is `publish` and `publish-local`.

Comment: I'd give `scalacOptions in publish` and `scalacOptions in publishLocal` a try (you could narrow them down, but I'll leave it to you as an exercise :)). I don't have a sample project now so I can't check it out myself. Would you mind sharing yours, on GitHub perhaps, if that suggestion doesn't work for you?

Comment: Does `publish` issue a recompile of all sources? Or are binaries for `test` and `compile` tasks in separate folders? Because what basically needs to happen is a recompile of the complete code to get rid of the assertions.

Comment: `publish` depends on configuration scope, be it `Test` or `Compile` (default). So, yes, there are different binaries for these different scopes. One could say, there are two `publish`'es (per configuration). `publish` asks `compile` to do its job, and when `compile`'s needed the sources get recompiled. Use `clean` before `publish` when in doubt.