# Define configuration with compiler plugin

Tags: sbt

I'd like to create a compile configuration which is the same as the default one but adds a compiler plugin. In my particular case, I  want to have a "dev" configuration but with the linter plugin (https://github.com/HairyFotr/linter) because it slows down compile times and there's no need to run it in production or continuous integration.

Now this is what I tried:

```scala
lazy val Dev = config("dev") extend Compile

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).configs(Dev).settings(
    inConfig(Dev)(addCompilerPlugin("org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.12")): _*)
```

and it *should* work, since when I `inspect dev:libraryDependencies`, it's what I expect it to be- it has `org.psywerx.hairyfotr:linter:0.1.12:plugin->default(compile)`. Normally if I add the library with a "plugin" scope, it does work for the default settings:

```
libraryDependencies += ("org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.12" % "plugin"
```

It just does not work if I add this under a different configuration, so there must be something else going on here.

Comment: When is this plugin supposed to run? When you say `sbt compile`?

Comment: And I assume, you've added `autoCompilerPlugins := true` in your project settings?

Comment: I'd like the plugin to run on "dev:compile" and not run on "compile". If you can do it the other way round, I may settle for that. And yes, I've also tried adding "autoCompilerPlugins := true", even though the plugin is activated without it in the compile phase if I just do "addCompilerPlugin(...)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solves the problem, but not exactly in a way was asked. Here's the full `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.14" % "test")

val linter = Command.command("linter")(state => {
  val linterJar = for {
    (newState, result) <- Project.runTask(fullClasspath in Test, state)
    cp <- result.toEither.right.toOption
    linter <- cp.find(
      _.get(moduleID.key).exists(mId =>
        mId.organization == "org.psywerx.hairyfotr" &&
          mId.name == "linter_2.11"))
  } yield linter.data.absolutePath

  val res = Project.runTask(scalacOptions, state)
  res match {
    case Some((newState, result)) =>
      result.toEither.right.foreach { defaultScalacOptions =>
        Project.runTask(compile in Test,
          Project.extract(state).append(
            scalacOptions := defaultScalacOptions ++ linterJar.map(p => Seq(s"-Xplugin:$p")).getOrElse(Seq.empty),
            newState))
      }
    case None => sys.error("Couldn't get defaultScalacOptions")
  }
  state
})

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).configs(Test).settings(commands ++= Seq(linter))
```

The fact that you return unmodified state means you don't change the project settings. So if you run `sbt linter`, you should get your project compiled with the additional `scalacOptions`, but if you run `compile` in the same sbt session, it will not use those additional settings.

The tricky thing here is that `scalacOptions` is actually a `TaskKey`, not a `SettingKey`. I don't know why is that, but to get its value, you have to run that task. One reason might be that in sbt you cannot make setting depending on a task, but you can make a task depending on a task. In other words, `scalacOptions` can depend on the other task value, and maybe internally it does, I haven't checked. If current answer will work for you, I can try and think about more elegant way of achieving the same result.

**EDIT:** modified the code to specify the `scalacOptions` for the linter plugin proper. Please note the plugin has to be a managed dependency, not just a downloaded jar, for this solution to work. If you want to have it unmanaged, there's a way, but I won't go into it for now. Additionally, I've taken a freedom of making it also work for testing code, for illustration purposes.

Comment: This means that the compile will be invoked twice essentially? Doesn't sound very encouraging especially for a compile that can take a couple of minutes.

Comment: The most important change to this code would be that the scalacOptions need to be changed based on the plugin classpath, as it's done in compilerPluginConfig, which invokes autoPlugins.

Comment: No, it will be invoked once. First you invoke `scalacOptions in Compile`, which is confusing, because it's a task, not a setting. Then you invoke `compile in Compile` with modified settings.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the actual code to include the plugin scalac option.

Comment: On first try it doesn't seem to do anything different than `compile` even if I add the plugin as a libraryDependency which it seems is necessary.

Comment: Did you manage to run this plugin without any scopes, vanilla style, like described in its documentation? Because it didn't run for me, like I already mentioned in previous comments. Maybe there's some other issue here...

Comment: Yes, it runs fine with `addCompilerPlugin("org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.12")`

Comment: Okay, finally managed to get to debug it properly. I've made it to run, check the updated code example, should work for you as well. Main problems were the not scoping the `fullClasspath` to `Compile` and module name not including the Scala version.

Comment: Yup, it works now, thanks! Even then, this is hardly a straightforward solution, which is of course not your fault at all, just probably a misdesign of this particular aspect of sbt. Also, it requires the plugin to be listed as a library dependency which might unintended side effects, like being included in an assembly jar. Still, thanks for arriving at a solution that I thought was not practically possible!

Comment: For the part of unnecessary including the plugin into final jar, I think you might scope everthing under `Test` config, i.e. use the `compile in Test`, `"org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.14" % "test"`, etc. This has another advantage of linting your test code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Defaults.scala in the source, it seems like the compile command is always taking the options from the compile scope. So if I'm correct, you can have only one set of compilation options!

This seems to be confirmed by the fact that `scalacOptions` behaves the same way, and this is also why I don't see a non-hacky answer for these similar questions:

- [Different scalac options for different scopes or tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416836/different-scalac-options-for-different-scopes-or-tasks)
- [Different compile options for tests and release in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371491/different-compile-options-for-tests-and-release-in-sbt)

I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

**EDIT**: FWIW, one might not be able to define another scalac options profile *in the same project*, but you could do so in a "different" project:

```
lazy val dev = (project in file(".")).
settings(target := baseDirectory.value / "target" / "dev").
settings(addCompilerPlugin("org.psywerx.hairyfotr" %% "linter" % "0.1.12"): _*)
```

This has the disadvantage that it has a separate output directory, so it will take more space and, more importantly, will not get incremental compiles between the two projects. However, after spending some time thinking about it, this may be by design. After all, even though linters don't, some scalac compilation options could conceivably change the output. This would make it meaningless to try to keep the metadata for incremental compilation from one set of scalac options to another. Thus different scalac options would indeed require different target directories.

Comment: I actually haven't managed to run this plugin at all, to my embarrassment. But if you are sure your problem is rooted in the `scalacOptions`, you have the following option: create a new `Command`, in which you'll modify the project scope by changing the `scalacOptions`, and run `compile` task manually with that modified scope.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it has the same pattern. I did think about redefining a command, but it seems like a lot of effort for just creating another set of compilation settings.

Comment: It's not a lot of effort, and you can copy and modify existing `scalacSettings`. I'll post an example in an answer soon.

Comment: OK, after reviewing Defaults.scala, I'm sure it's using the scalacOptions mechanism- it's basically adding a -Xplugin:path. So OK, maybe it's not a lot of effort, but doesn't seem as elegant as configuring under a certain scope. I'm curious to see your solution of course.